# In Go, can both a type and a pointer to a type implement an interface?

Tags: pointers, interface, struct, go

For example in the following example:

```
type Food interface {
    Eat() bool
}

type vegetable_s struct {
    //some data
}

type Vegetable *vegetable_s

type Salt struct {
    // some data
}

func (p Vegetable) Eat() bool {
    // some code
}

func (p Salt) Eat() bool {
    // some code
}
```

Do `Vegetable` and `Salt` both satisfy `Food`, even though one is a pointer and the other is directly a struct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is easy to get by [compiling the code](http://play.golang.org/p/ONYt_IDgUN):

```
prog.go:19: invalid receiver type Vegetable (Vegetable is a pointer type)
```

The error is based on the [specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) requirement of:

> The receiver type must be of the form T or *T where T is a type name. The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; **it must not be a pointer or interface type** and it must be declared in the same package as the method.

(Emphasizes mine)

The declaration:

```
type Vegetable *vegetable_s
```

declares a *pointer* type, ie. `Vegetable` is not eligible as a method receiver.

Comment: anyone know why design like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
package main

type Food interface {
    Eat() bool
}

type vegetable_s struct {}
type Vegetable vegetable_s
type Salt struct {}

func (p *Vegetable) Eat() bool {return false}
func (p Salt) Eat() bool {return false}

func foo(food Food) {
   food.Eat()
}

func main() {
    var f Food
    f = &Vegetable{}
    f.Eat()
    foo(&Vegetable{})
    foo(Salt{})
}
```

Comment: What I wanted it to do was, for a function `func foo(x Food) {...}`, call it as `foo(vegetable_pointer)` but `foo(salt_value)`.

Comment: @Matt I added the foo function to the answer above. The objects are automatically "wrapped" in the target interface if they are passed to as parameters to a method the expects an interface.