# Pointer to struct satisfy interface

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I scanned the Revel framework's Go code and it seems that pointers satisfy interface requirements. See the snippets below.

```
type Result interface {
    Apply(req *Request, resp *Response)
}

type RenderTextResult struct {
    text string
}

func (r RenderTextResult) Apply(req *Request, resp *Response) {
    resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK, "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    resp.Out.Write([]byte(r.text))
}

func (c *Controller) RenderText(text string, objs ...interface{}) Result {
    finalText := text
    if len(objs) > 0 {
        finalText = fmt.Sprintf(text, objs...)
    }
    return &RenderTextResult{finalText}
}
```

What's the reasoning behind this? The framework is returning a struct value instead of a struct pointer for rendering JSON, though:

```
type RenderJsonResult struct {
    obj      interface{}
    callback string
}

// Uses encoding/xml.Marshal to return XML to the client.
func (c *Controller) RenderXml(o interface{}) Result {
    return RenderXmlResult{o}
}
```

I can't seem to grasp the subtle (?) differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [named type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) can satisfy an interface. It does not matter whether the type is a pointer, a channel or a function value as long as it implements the methods the interface demands.

Example of a function satisfying an interface ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/rcRH0blz6w)):

```
type Printer interface {
    Print(string)
}

type funcPrinter func() string

func (f funcPrinter) Print(s string) { 
     fmt.Println(s + f()) 
}
```

This leaves the question why one would return a pointer rather than a value or vice versa.
If you pass objects around all the time then it is a good idea to use pointers as they are
always of a small fixed length instead of all the values.

The following line results in having the struct copied to the caller:

```
return RenderXmlResult{o}
```

While this call will return a pointer to the struct placed somewhere in the heap.

```
return &RenderXmlResult{o}
```

Comment: Thanks. Two questions, though: (i) why do they mix the different approaches in the Revel framework? I can't seem to get it. (ii) Your example is very helpful, it feels weird to create funcs on funcs but that's just consequent I think. So when I call `Print(s string)`, the receiver is called by value, right? Is it possible to define it as `func (f *funcPrinter) Print(s string)`? I tried it but Go wouldn't accept it.

Comment: It seems there is no such thing as a pure function pointer in Go - that might answer (ii) (see also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902127/in-go-can-both-a-type-and-a-pointer-to-a-type-implement-an-interface)). Still leaves me wondering why the difference in the framework exists ([link](https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/controller.go))

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pointers implicitly have all the methods of the type they point to. See the FAQ sections  ["Why do T and *T have different method sets?"](http://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets) and ["Methods on values or pointers?"](http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

Comment: Thanks, very useful links for further reading. I ended up accepting the first answer, because all answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Methods associated with a type are also available on pointers to that type.  So if `r` is a `*RenderTextResult` variable, then `r.Apply(...)` is equivalent to `(*r).Apply()`.

In most respects, the `Apply` method will act like any method associated with `*RenderTextResult` directly, although it won't be able to modify the contents of the struct, since it receives a copy of the struct rather than a pointer to the original.

This means that the methods on `RenderTextResult` can be used to let `*RenderTextResult` satisfy the `Result` interface.

Comment: The difference between `(*r).Apply()` and `*r.Apply`is that the latter would point to the Apply func, right?